# Using the NetflixOSS stack (especially the RSS-Recipe Tutorial), how do I communicate between the middle-tier with the edge-tier?

Tags: netflix

The middletier and edge tier are in separate folders and packages, so I can't simply call say a middletier class from an edgetier class. How do I communicate between these two tiers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the said example both those components run on servers (Jetty and Netty). You should just pass REST calls between them to communicate. For instance, you can fire up both servers and then issue a GET request from one component to the other, and have the other listen for the request and perform actions accordingly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. is there another way to do this besides making server to server calls?